# Is there a way to ensure two arguments passed to a function are treated as the first and third argument in C++?

Tags: c++, overloading, default-arguments

Suppose there is a function with the following prototype:

```
void fun (int = 10, int = 20, int = 30, int = 40);
```

If this function is called by passing 2 arguments to it, how can we make sure that these arguments are treated as first and third, whereas, the second and the fourth are taken as defaults.

Comment: Function overloading and forwarding.

Comment: Reorder the arguments so that the first and third arguments are first and second. There is no way in C++ to skip an argument like this.

Comment: [Named arguments](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/) as in Python.

Answer (score 5):

```
// three and four argument version
void fun (int a, int b, int c, int d = 40)
{
    ...
}

// two argument version
void fun (int a, int c)
{
     fun(a, 20, c, 40);
}

// one and zero argument version
void fun(int a = 10)
{
     fun(a, 20, 30, 40);
}
```

But really my advice would be don't.

Comment: @Scheff Well yes, I only provided the answer because the other answer was incorrect (in the detail) and I want to show how it could be done. But normally my answer would be don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the `Args` structure like:

```cpp
struct Args {
   int a = 10;
   int b = 20;
   int c = 30;
   int d = 40;
};
```

and then you would have the following:

```cpp
void fun(Args);

fun({.a=60, .c=70}); // a=60, b=20, c=70, d=40
```

Besides this approach, you can use [`NamedType`](https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType) library that implements named arguments in C++. For more usage info, check [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/).

**UPDATE**

[Designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers) feature is available by **GCC and CLANG extensions** and, from **C++20**, it is available by C++ standard.

Comment: What version of C++ has the `{.a=60, .c=70}` syntax? Never seen it before.

Comment: @john GCC and CLANG have extensions implementing this designated initializers feature. But from C++20 it is part of the [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)

Answer (score 2):

This one works, it uses function overloading.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(int a = 10, int b = 20, int c = 30, int d = 40){
    cout << "a = " << a << "\nb = " << b << "\nc = " << c << "\nd = " << d;
}

void fun(float a, float c, int b = 20, int d = 40){
    cout << "a = " << a << "\nb = " << b << "\nc = " << c << "\nd = " << d;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Enter two numbers : ";
    float a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    fun(a, b);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more elegant way would be using [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and `std::placeholders` like this:

```cpp
#include <functional>

void fun (int = 10, int = 20, int = 30, int = 40) {}

using namespace std::placeholders;
auto bindedFun = std::bind(fun, _1, 20, _2, 40);

int main()
{
  bindedFun(1234, 5678);
}
```

I find it more clearer and easier to understand. Also it is less prown to errors imo! And if you don't wanna have a global variable to hold your bind, you could either declare it locally or stuff your binds in a struct.

Comment: A lambda is more elegant than (and is generally always preferred over) `std::bind()`, eg: `auto bindedFun = [](int a, int b){ fun(a, 20, b, 40); }`

Comment: Yes that's also a solution, I completely agree on that one!

Comment: This doesn't exactly solve the problem. It states that the function should treat the two arguments as first and third parameters only if exactly 2 arguments are provided. The function should still be able to support four arguments. I think function overloading as mentioned by others is the way to go here.